# AES encryption using Php , javascript and vise versa

Tags: javascript, php, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am doing client side encryption using javascript and server side using PHP. Both side we are using same key and IV.

**Php Encryption :**

```
$string='test data';

$output = '';
    $encrypt_method = 'AES-256-CBC';
    $secret_key     = 'secret key in hex';
    $secret_iv      = 'iv in hex';
    $key            = hash('sha256',$secret_key);

$output   = openssl_encrypt($string,$encrypt_method,$key,0,$initialization_vector);

//Encrypted text in php
$output   = base64_encode($output);
```

**Javascript Encryption Code:**

```
var key = 'secret key in hex';
key = CryptoJS.SHA256(key);            
var ivHex = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(' IV in hex ');            
var options = { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv:ivHex};
var obj='test data';
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(obj,key ,options);
var encryptedBase64 = encrypted.toString();

//Encrypted text in javascript    
console.log(encryptedBase64);
```

Both are giving different output. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Stick to openssl_encrypt(). Best method is AES-256-CTR and of course use IV with 16  chars.

Answer (score 1):

1. `$secret_iv` is defined, but an undefined `$initialization_vector` is used in `openssl_encrypt()`.
2. For the fourth argument, you don't want to pass `0`, you want to pass `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` (a constant).
3. You're passing `hash('sha256', $secret_key)` in PHP but using `secret_key` directly in Javascript.

   - Note: Your key derivation (`hash('sha256', $some_text_input)`) is very weak. Consider PBKDF2-SHA256 instead.

**Important:** AES-CBC without an HMAC is vulnerable to [padding-oracle attacks](https://robertheaton.com/2013/07/29/padding-oracle-attack/). You should [always use authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).

An example of secure encryption looks like [this](https://3v4l.org/9PN2m). Decryption is a little more involved.

Comment: Good answer.  To future readers, also note that as of PHP 7.1, AES in GCM mode is supported, which is likely a better fit for new work than CTR mode since it eliminates the need for an HMAC.